# JAVA Protected variable not allowed to be access though an object in child class of different package

Tags: java

Given two files:

```
package pkgA;
public class Foo {
int a = 5;
protected int b = 6;
}
```

---

```
1  package pkgB;
2  import pkgA.*;
3  public class Fiz extends Foo {
4     public static void main(String[] args) {
5        Foo f = new Foo();
6        System.out.print(" " + f.a);
7        System.out.print(" " + f.b);
8        System.out.print(" " + new Fiz().a);
9        System.out.println(" " + new Fiz().b);
10    }
11  }
```

What is the result? (Choose all that apply.)

A. 5 6 5 6
B. 5 6 followed by an exception
C. Compilation fails with an error on line 6
D. Compilation fails with an error on line 7
E. Compilation fails with an error on line 8
F. Compilation fails with an error on line 9

Ref: SCJP 1.6 Kathy_Sierra: 
**As per Book Answer is C, D, E**

**Why NOT 'F'?**
can anybody please explain

Comment: copy it to your IDE and see the result by yourself

Comment: line 9: `public class Fiz extends Foo {` is a perfectly valid line of code, so there's no reason for a compilation error there (as long as it's at a correct location in the file, which it is in this example).

Comment: I actually think it is a good question that most people may overlook when they talk about `protected` in Java.  Blaming OP not testing in an IDE is not reasonable, as he is not asking what is the correct answer for that SCJP question, he is asking "Why NOT 'F'" which I think is a valid question (although OP can give a bit more background on why he think F should also be part of the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Counting them down I assume that line 9 is supposed to be this line:

```
System.out.println(" " + new Fiz().b);
```

Protected variables are accessible to subclasses. `Fiz` is a subclass of `Foo` so it can access `b`. It can do so in a static context.

Comment: that doesn't explain why `f.b` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

`protected` is a bit interesting in Java.  Although we always says "protected" give access to subclass of different package, it is not the whole picture.

For example, if you have `Child` extending `Parent`, and there is a protected member in `Parent`.  What you can do in `Child` is to access that protected member of `Child`, not even of `Parent`.  Sounds a bit strange right although they sounds the same thing?

Quoted from Core Java 9th Edition:

> However, the Manager class methods can peek inside the hireDay field
>   of Manager objects only, not of other Employee objects. This
>   restriction is made so that you can’t abuse the protected mechanism by
>   forming subclasses just to gain access to the protected fields

(class `Manager` extends `Employee`, and there is a `hireDay` protected member in `Employee`)

For example,

```
public class Manager extends Employee {
    // accessing protected member of itself
    public void foo1() {   
        System.out.println("" + this.hireDay);  // OK
    }

    // access protected member of instance of same type
    public void foo2(Manager manager) {  
        System.out.println("" + manager.hireDay);  // OK
    }

    // access protected member of instance of super-class
    public void foo3(Employee employee) {
        System.out.println("" + employee.hireDay);  // NOT ALLOWED!
    }
}
```