# Protected variables can be accessed within Child Class or Child Object

Tags: java, inheritance, protected

Is the `protected` variable of a `parentObject` be accessed from any child `Object`? or can be accessed only by only the particular `childObject`? I have a scenario which clearly expresses my doubt.

I have two classes `ParentClass` and `ChildClass`. `ParentClass` is parent of `ChildClass`. I have a `protected` variable in `ParentClass` named `protVar`. It is of type `Object`. Then, I create two `Object`s like the following.

```
ParentClass p1 = new ParentClass();
ChildClass c1 = new ChildClass();
c1.callMethod(p1); // Here I want to access protected variable of p1 which is a separate object and Not initialized within c1 as super()
```

Now will I be able to access the `protVar` of `p1` from `c1`?

Comment: u can access protected variables of super class in sub class

Comment: Is it really so difficult to just try it?

Comment: Also what u want to try is unclear.Passing object of parent class in subclass..

Comment: @EJP I just want if there is any technical explanation than trial and error mode..

Comment: @Youngistan I have built a code only with using the ParentClass. I do not want to change the flow of code since in my program, I am introducing multiple child for the ParentClass and use in different scenario. But each needs the parentClass values. Instead of passing all values, I am sending the parentObject so each child can take what is needed inside.

Comment: kk @SantronManibharathi so u get the solution or still confuse on protected ??

Comment: @Youngistan This is not a mobile phone. Please make an effort to speed correctly and in general write clear standard English.

Comment: @EJP I am not good in english so may be it make difficult for others to understand

Comment: @Youngistan I am working on the solution. Seems it could take some more time to complete.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disclaimer: the answer is copied from [my answer of another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21929828/395202).  However no answer from that question is accepted.  I believe it also suit this question therefore I am copying the content with some minor editing to here.

`protected` is a bit interesting in Java. Although we always says "protected" give access to subclass of different package, it is not the whole picture.

For example, if you have `Child` extending `Parent`, and there is a protected member in `Parent`. What you can do in `Child` is to access that protected member of `Child`, but not even that protected member of `Parent`. Sounds a bit strange right although they sounds the same thing?

Quoted from Core Java 9th Edition:

> However, the Manager class methods can peek inside the hireDay field
>   of Manager objects only, not of other Employee objects. This
>   restriction is made so that you can’t abuse the protected mechanism by
>   forming subclasses just to gain access to the protected fields

(class Manager extends Employee, and there is a hireDay protected member in Employee, and Manager and Employee are located in *DIFFERENT* package)

For example,

```
public class Manager extends Employee {
    // accessing protected member of itself
    public void foo1() {   
        System.out.println("" + this.hireDay);  // OK
    }

    // access protected member of instance of same type
    public void foo2(Manager manager) {  
        System.out.println("" + manager.hireDay);  // OK
    }

    // access protected member of instance of super-class
    public void foo3(Employee employee) {
        System.out.println("" + employee.hireDay);  // NOT ALLOWED!
    }
}
```

Which means, protected member allow child class from another package to access through reference of that child class (either `this`, or another reference that is-a child class)

And, be specific to OP's answer: if `callMethod` is declared in `ChildClass`, then NO, you cannot do it and it will not even compile.  However if `callMethod` is declared in `ParentClass` then everything is fine, because it is simply `ParentClass` accessing protected member of a `ParentClass` instance.

---

Update:

Given criticisms in comment, I think it worth to go to JLS to see what it say:

(Quoted from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2.1 about Access to a protected Member, second bullet)

> If the access is by a field access expression E.Id, or a method
>   invocation expression E.Id(...), or a method reference expression E ::
>   Id, where E is a Primary expression (§15.8), then the access is
>   permitted if and only if the type of E is S or a subclass of S

This is essentially what I was trying to deliver in the answer:

Within `Manager` class, `manager.hireDay` works because `manager` is a primary expression, and the access is permitted because type of `manager` is `Manager` or subclass of `Manager`.

So, based on JLS, why `manager.hireDay` works ***DOES*** have relationship with type of `manager` (being the same type).

Comment: The answer is misleading. In second part , `manager.hireDay` does not work because you are accessing protected member of instance of same type. Once `manager` inherits  `hireDay` , `hireDay` is now a protected field of `Manager` class. Hence , even a complete different class , `Entrepreneur` will be able to access hireday using an instance of `Manager` ( `manager.hireDay` ) as long as `Enterpreneur` belongs to the same package as `Manager`.

Comment: @Rpant I believe you haven't understand the rationale behind.  When we are talking about `protected` in the example above, of course we have to make sure that the classes are from different package, so you do not gain accessibility through package/default (which is also part of `protected`).  If things are put under same package, `protected` or package/default makes no difference.  *And*, in above example, `manager.hireDay` DOES work.  Please read it again to make sure you really understand :)

Comment: I am not saying it DOESN'T work. I am saying the explanation you are giving as to why it works ( its instance of same type) is wrong. In the explanation I gave , I am still considering , `Employee` and `Manager` to belong to different package. However `Enterpreneur` belongs to the same package as `Manager`

Comment: *"In second part , manager.hireDay does not work because "* that's what you wrote.  And, I do understand people can use different way to understand this behavior but what I wrote (which based on a book) is the actual effect you will observe (i.e. you can only access thru ref of same class, given parent class in different package).

Comment: @Rpant and, if you are interested, you may check JLS: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2.1 , the 2nd bullet point:  ***If the access is by a field access expression E.Id, or a method invocation expression E.Id(...), or a method reference expression E :: Id, where E is a Primary expression (§15.8), then the access is permitted if and only if the type of E is S or a subclass of S.*** which is what described in the answer

Comment: ""In second part , manager.hireDay does not work because "" , I meant ""In second part , manager.hireDay works not because (of the explanation)""

Comment: As I said before, you may use a different semantic to understand. However please read the JLS as quoted. What I was explaining is exactly what the JLS saying. "Access (of protected field hireday) is permitted if and only if the type of E (manager in the example) is S or subclass of S (Manager in this example)"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a derived class can access a protected variable in a base class via both 'super' and another reference to the base class.

**EDIT** It should be noted that I am here assuming the same package as you didn't state anything about different packages. The rules are different otherwise.

Comment: Ui. Sorry to say, but this is simply not true! A protected member (field or method) can only be accessed via the super mechanism. If you get a reference in another way, you can only access this member when being in the same package (as protected also includes package visibility)!

Comment: I believe both EJP and @Seelenvirtuose are wrong.  So happened I have answered a similar question recently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21929828/395202

Comment: No, I am not wrong. You cannot access protected fields from an object that you just have a reference from (e.g. through a simple variable). But keep in mind, that this is true only, if your accessing code resides in another package. If it is the same package, you can access the protected fields, as protected includes package visibility.

Comment: It's extremely strange that you should all think this isn't correct. I tested it before I posted. A method `ChildClass.method(ParentClass p)` can access `p.protectedVariable.`

Comment: Maybe you forgot to put them in different packages.

Comment: @Radiodef There is nothing in the question about different packages.

Comment: I guess the OP could have provided that detail but I find that to be a kind of specious technicality since your answer didn't make the distinction either. If they are in the same package then whether or not one is derived from the other doesn't matter.

Comment: @EJP that's strange, because, in my answer, I have tried and found that in `Manager.foo3(Employee emp)`, it cannot access `emp.protectedVar` (of course, given Manager and Employee are in different package).  If it is in the same package, it is quite meaningless because the "package" accessibility will always allow you to access those protected member if you reside in same package.

Comment: According to your edit, I removed my downvote. But whether or not the OP mentioned it, the detail of being in the same package or not is so important when talking about access modifiers, that any good answer should explain it.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose That would be why I edited it into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your child class and Parent class in same package than you can access this object directly [If you wish], Otherwise you have two option.
 1 - Create a public getter method in Parent class and access your protected field using that method 
 2 - Inside child class fetch the Parent protected field using reflection like given below

```
public void callMethod(ParentClass o) {
    try {
        Field f = o.getClass().getDeclaredField("protVar");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Object value = f.get(o);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Even though the question is old , I am trying my best to explain , since this is a fairly common question for java newbies.

Consider Employee class in package p1.

```
package p1;
public class Employee{
    protected String hireDay = "hireday";
}
```

Manager extends Employee and is in a different package.

```
package p2;
public class Manager extends p1.Employee {
 //now even Manager class has hireDay protected variable that was defined in Employee class.
 //Since Manager class has protected variable hireDay , for any manager m1 , we can access hireDay as m1.hireDay ONLY within package p2.
}
```

Enterprenur class extends Manager and is in package p3.

```
package p3;
public class Enterpreneur extends p2.Manager{

    //now  Enterpreneur class has inherited hireDay protected variable that  Employee class had. (see comments in Employee class.)
 //Since Enterpreneur class has protected variable hireDay , for any Enterpreneur e , we can access hireDay as e.hireDay ONLY within package p3.



    //the following will work because using Enterpreneur reference e , we can access e.hireday within package p3 , this has nothing to do with
    //the fact that right now our code is present in Enterpreneur class , like the other answer said. Note the method is static.
    public static void printhireDay(Enterpreneur e){
        System.out.println("hireday is :" + e.hireDay);
    }

    //this will work because using this reference we can only access protected variable in the same class(Enterpreneur) or in a subclass.
    public void printhireDay(){
        System.out.println("hireday is :" + this.hireDay);
    }

    // This shouldn't work because using manager reference , we can only access protected field within package p2.
    /* public printhireDay(Manager m){
        System.out.println("hireday is :" + m.hireDay)
    }*/
}
```

Now within the root package , we have this class to test.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        p3.Enterpreneur e = new p3.Enterpreneur();
        //both of these work.
        e.printhireDay();
        //printing by passing the reference e.
        p3.Enterpreneur.printhireDay(e);


     }
}
```

Comment: You still miss the point. If you only understand this by "the field can be accessed because it is in same package", you cannot explain why in Manager class, it is valid to do `anEntrepreuerRef.hireDay`

Comment: Wow , I was wrong .. Did not expect this to work , but it does work. I was expecting `anEntrepreuerRef.hireDay` to be accessible only within package p3. I however still did not get your point across about why it works.

Comment: You may read the JLS I quoted and my answer again. It works because it is a protected field (declared in superclass of another package), and it is accessing thru reference with type same as (or subclass of) itself.

Comment: And, I think you also have one confusion of accessibility common to Java newbies: In your example, you explicitly mentioned some method being `static`, for which I believe you expect there is something special for accessibility related to `static`.  However, in accessibility control in Java, it makes not difference for static or instance method.

Comment: I wonder if the JLS proved to you the correctness of my answer (and incorrectness in yours)?  It will be great if you can clarify and withdraw your downvote in my original answer (if it is from you), so that it makes new comer easier to follow.  THanks

Comment: I up-voted your answer again. In your answer , if you can add code in Employee class to access manager.hireDay, that will clearly demo access of protected member variable of sub-type. Your code already demos same type and super type.