# Can we call a Arraylist from a class to another class, and can be used by all methods in the 'another' class? No static - Java

Tags: java

Can we call a protected ArrayList from one class to another class, where it can be used for "all methods" in the 'another' class.
for example:

```
public class ArrayListClass {
protected Arraylist<SomeClass> someClass = new Arraylist<>();
}
```

Then I want to use the ArrayList in all of the methods in another class

```
public class another {
private void method1() {
//use the same arraylist here
}
private void method2() {
//use the same arraylist here
} 
public void method3() {
// use the same arraylist here
}
```

Comment: either another should be inherited from ArrayListClass or it should accept it as argument

Comment: Do you mean "public class another extends ArrayListClass {}" ?

Comment: yes, it is inheritance syntax in java

Comment: Ok, I will try that out

Comment: not working when I add things in the ArrayList, the other method doesn't include it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Protected variables can be accessed within Child Class or Child Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139513/protected-variables-can-be-accessed-within-child-class-or-child-object)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches you can take. In general, you're trying to pass data/variable from one Class to another.

But since you're using `protected` access modifier, your options will be limited.

If the 'AnotherClass' is in the same package, you could use inheritance (as has been mentioned in the comments) or you could instantiate a new instance as advised in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72671717/19365920).

If 'AnotherClass' is in a different package, the only option you have is to use inheritance.

If this doesn't work, consider changing the access modifier.

More info on Protected access modifier:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/protected-keyword-in-java-with-examples/

Answer (score -1):

Sure, just add access methods to `ArrayListClass`:

```
 public class ArrayListClass {
    protected Arraylist<String> string = new Arraylist();
    public getTheList () { return string; }
    // more access methods
 }
```

In your class `Another`, create in instance of  your ArrayListClass:

```
public class another {
private ArrayListClass alc;
public another () {       // default constructor 
    alc = new ArrayListClass ();        
}
private void method1() {
    alc.getTheList.add ("Foo");    
}
```

But, if you do that, you should think about why `string` is `protected` in the first place.

Comment: it is just an example, not the real ArrayList I put (not a string), but I think I will try your way to see if it works.

Comment: @worker2, -- I made a mistake in my example. Poor editing on my part.  I hope the edit I made fixed it.

Comment: _I made a mistake in my example_ actually, you still do: you violate java naming conventions (better not replicate errors from the questions)

Comment: @worker2 There was another mistake in my code. I used `.put` instead of `.add`. I corrected that one, also.